# Error while trying to use warble on ChiliProject for JRuby/Jetty deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jetty, jruby, warbler, chiliproject

I'm trying to use warbler on ChiliProject (a Redmine fork, Rails 2.3 app) to deploy it in a Java Jetty web server. But when I run warble at the projects root folder, it fails with the given error message:

```
$ warble  --trace
warble aborted!
undefined method `gems' for #<Rails::VendorGemSourceIndex:0x2e9267fe>
/Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:260:in `all_specs'
/Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/source.rb:172:in `installed_specs'
/Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/source.rb:162:in `fetch_specs'
/Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/index.rb:7:in `build'
/Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/source.rb:161:in `fetch_specs'
/Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/source.rb:70:in `specs'
/Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `index'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1603:in `each'
/Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/definition.rb:158:in `index'
/Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/index.rb:7:in `build'
/Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/definition.rb:157:in `index'
/Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/definition.rb:151:in `resolve'
/Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/definition.rb:90:in `specs'
/Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/definition.rb:135:in `specs_for'
/Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/definition.rb:124:in `requested_specs'
/Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3/gems/warbler-1.3.2/lib/warbler/traits/bundler.rb:102:in `bundler_specs'
/Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3/gems/warbler-1.3.2/lib/warbler/traits/bundler.rb:38:in `add_bundler_gems'
/Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3/gems/warbler-1.3.2/lib/warbler/traits/bundler.rb:29:in `after_configure'
/Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3/gems/warbler-1.3.2/lib/warbler/traits.rb:32:in `after_configure'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1603:in `each'
/Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3/gems/warbler-1.3.2/lib/warbler/traits.rb:32:in `after_configure'
/Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3/gems/warbler-1.3.2/lib/warbler/config.rb:172:in `initialize'
/Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3/gems/warbler-1.3.2/lib/warbler/task.rb:48:in `initialize'
/Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3/gems/warbler-1.3.2/lib/warbler/application.rb:27:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:61:in `run'
/Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3/gems/warbler-1.3.2/lib/warbler/application.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3/gems/warbler-1.3.2/bin/warble:11:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1063:in `load'
/Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3/bin/warble:19:in `(root)'
```

I'm using JRuby 1.6.3, JDK 1.6, warbler 1.3.2 and ChiliProject 2.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I sadly have to disappoint you, as we don't fully support JRuby yet. On the other hand, there are probably "only" encoding issues left to fix so if you are careful, things should work out just okay.

That said, it looks like Rails 2.3 doesn't play too well with Bundler here. If you drop the following file into `lib/redmine/core_ext/vendor_gem_source_index.rb` of your ChiliProject dirctory, you should be able to run warbler.

```
class Rails::VendorGemSourceIndex
  def gems
    @installed_source_index.gems.merge @vendor_source_index.gems
  end
end
```

You still need to configure warbler to use the correct bundler groups. As warbler does it's own thing here (and as I haven't yet used warbler with bundled apps) you might need top find out how to configure this. Have a look into the [Gemfile](https://github.com/chiliproject/chiliproject/blob/stable/Gemfile) and our [Bundler page](https://www.chiliproject.org/projects/chiliproject/wiki/Bundler) for more information.

And if you are nagging enough, we might one day officially support this :) Also, more friendly people can be found in our own [Forums](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/boards) and on [IRC](https://www.chiliproject.org/projects/chiliproject/wiki/IRC).

Comment: Please add support to JRuby =(

Comment: Please create an issue in https://www.chiliproject.org. Please try to add how you intend to use it i.e. the workflow how you'd deploy the app. I'm really not that familiar with JRuby/warbler but would try to work on that.